# Pack multiple assemblies with dotnet pack

Tags: package, .net-core, nuget-package

Just as the question says really, how can I pack multiple projects / assemblies using dotnet pack?

Using VS2017 with new csproj files.

Comment: Do you want to pack them into a single .nupkg?  Or do you want one .nupkg per project?

Comment: I mean into one nuget package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've looked into doing this in depth, and the only way I got things working was to make my own nuspec file. I used dotnet build -C release to build the individual projects, and I used my nuspec file to pull in the multiple assemblies into the 1 package.

Unfortunately it seems, the big idea with dotnet pack was to associate each project with a separate dll. If you have multiple projects, the idea was to pack each project, and still rely on package references.

Answer (score 31):

Include assemblies what you need in csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\Release\net46\Newtonsoft.Json.dll">
      <PackagePath>lib\net46\</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

also if you want to include assembly from your solution you can do this in the same way, but to exclude dependency to another nuget package use **PrivateAssets** tag

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\Release\net46\My.Contracts.dll">
      <PackagePath>lib\net46\</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="My.Contracts.csproj">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this also worked for me. The path can be a bit more generic:

`<Content Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\*.dll">
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)\</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>`

Comment: In my case it was required to add `<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>` child to the `Content` element

Comment: @VolkervonEinem the path can be even more generic using the `OutDir` variable `<Content Include="$(OutDir)\*.dll"><PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>`

Comment: @oleksa both things did unfortunately not work for me. using OutDir threw me an error of not being able to find a DLL. using TargetFramework put my dll directlry into lib